# Is this a good alternative to react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I don't want to use redux because there's too much boilerplate. So I am looking for a way to share a global state between components. Is it ok to pass the whole state of the App (root) component?

I have no issue with it so far but there must be a hole down the road, is there?

```
<HashRouter>
    <App />
</HashRouter>


<Switch>
<Route exact path='/' render={props => <TheListForm appState={this.state} app={this} />} />
<Route exact path='/myvideos' render={props => <MyVideos appState={this.state} app={this} />} />
</Switch>
```

So in my child components I have "this.props.appState" which contains the equivalent of the redux store and I can update it simply by doing:

```
this.props.app.setState({name:"bob"});
```

Comment: This pattern is very problematic, because you will have no idea who changed what because everyone has access. But checkout [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a smaller, with less boilerplate and with a lower learning curve state management library, you could check out [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx). You want to use a state management library, if you component exceeds more than a few child component, because your app will rerender everything on every change. With this.props.appData.setState and a form your while app would rerender if the user types something. It also breaks the react one way data flow concept.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you build a large scale project and there are so many hierarchies.
A includes B, B to C, ..., Y to Z.
If you want to pass the props from A to Z, you must set properties of all components from B-Z.

In that case, Redux is very useful and you only correct 2 components A and Z.
And also you can implement the bi-directional data flow with Redux.

Comment: Not sure to understand, but passing those 2 props is simpler to me than implementing the redux's connect mapStateToProp & mapDispatchToProps.

Answer (score 0):

https://rootzjs.org/ you should give it a try with this one. dead easy to use.